# wrapper function in fgets()

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fgets, null-terminated

I seek for an expert in c programming. Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void main()
{
char name[100][52],selection[2]="Y";
int x,nname=1;
float sales;

do
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(name[nname],51,stdin); // i need put a wrapper in here
    printf("Enter sales: ");
    scanf("%f",&sales);
    if (sales<1000)
        printf("%s\tgood\n",name[nname++]);
    else
        printf("%s\tvry good\n",name[nname++]);
    printf("Enter another name?(Y/N)");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(selection,2,stdin);
    *selection=toupper(*selection);
}while(nname<=100 && *selection=='Y');
for(x=1;x<nname;x++)
    printf("%s\n",name[x]); // want print the result without(newline) /n

printf("END\n");
system("pause");
}
```

How do I print the names without being separated by new lines?

Comment: the code compiles on my machine

Comment: Yup, I know, I want to print the result like this:
`name1 name2 name3` it's just in a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
printf("%s ", name[x]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s\n", name[x]);
```

The `\n` character is creating the new lines.

## Edit

`fgets` apparently reads newlines into the buffer - you can strip the newline with

```
name[nname][strlen(name[nname])-2] = '\0';
```

Comment: i have edited the coding, i need 2-d array for printing collected string in result

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, i have tried, but it is still printing in another line

Comment: Make sure you are running the recompiled executable. Delete the old file and compile again.

Comment: Yup, tried, as I know the fgets() function will auto create a new line after EOS.

Comment: this is also works!! but i use get_s() is also works, so can i know which one is better between fgets() and gets_s()?

Comment: @Wilson: you could use the up arrow, as well! ;)

Comment: @Wilson let me quote from `man gets`: `Never  use gets().` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)

Comment: osp... sorry for my careless :)

Comment: yup, I know that but in MVS2010 the compiler ask me to use `gets_s()` instead of `gets()`. but at the end that I heard someone said that `fgets()`is better than the others. This make me confuse and don't know which one is better security.

Comment: I didn't know about `gets_s()`, but from what I can gather online it is fine. Just use `gets_s()`.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled it with GCC 4.4.1 - MinGW and it works fine. 
It launched only a warning. This is the result:

```
 warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

---

Now it works as you expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <string.h> // strlen()

void main() {
    char name[100][52],selection[2]="Y";
    int x,nname=1;
    float sales;

    do {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(name[nname],51,stdin); // i need put a wrapper in here
        for (x=0; x<strlen(name[nname]); x++){ // this will discarge the \n
        if (name[nname][x] == '\n')
            name[nname][x] = '\0';
        }
        printf("Enter sales: ");
        scanf("%f",&sales);
        if (sales<1000)
            printf("%s\tgood\n",name[nname++]);
        else
            printf("%s\tvry good\n",name[nname++]);
        printf("Enter another name?(Y/N)");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(selection,2,stdin);
        *selection=toupper(*selection);
    } while(nname<=100 && *selection=='Y');
    for(x=1; x<nname; x++)
        printf("%s ",name[x]); // want print the result without(newline) /n

    printf("\nEND\n"); // inserted \n before END
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The coding is work but the result I need it to be all name in a line example `name1 name2 name3`